# Base Activity abstract class methods not executing in other activities

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, abstract-class

i have created a base activity with a progressbar and a framelayout to inflate other activity layouts which are extending base activity. but when i call the showProgressbar method from base activity in other activities. nothing happens. it doesn't showup.

> activity_base.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/activity_content"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> BaseActivity.class

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressBar mProgressbar;
    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {

        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base,null);
        FrameLayout frameLayout = constraintLayout.findViewById(R.id.activity_content);
        mProgressbar = constraintLayout.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID,frameLayout,true);
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);
    }

    public void showProgressBar(boolean visibility){

        mProgressbar.setVisibility(visibility ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);

    }

}
```

> MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_password);

        showProgressBar(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace this : `super.setContentView(layoutResID)`
with this : `super.setContentView(constraintLayout);` you are trying to have base layout and child activity layout and you are inflating them correctly but when you pass super.setContentView your child layoutResID all above code is ignored.